# godot how to know if a click is inside a sprite :

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a p12 Sprite that have a KinematicBody2D and the KinematicBody2D have a Collision polygon2d.

I'am trying to check if a mouse clik is inside p12 :

```
var inside : bool = p12.get_node("KinematicBody2D").has_point(to_local(pos))
```

or

```
var inside : bool = p12.get_node("KinematicBody2D").get_node("Collision polygon2d").has_point(to_local(pos))
```

Are not working.

Any idea how to check if the click is inside my sprite ?

here is my code :

```
func wich_piece(mouse_pos : Vector2 ):
    for piece in pieces:
        var inside : bool = ((piece as Sprite).get_node("KinematicBody2D") as KinematicBody).has_point(to_local(mouse_pos))
        if inside:
            return piece
    return null
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a p12 Sprite that have a KinematicBody2D and the KinematicBody2D have a Collision polygon2d.

This is an odd setup, it means that if you move the `KinematicBody2D` the `Sprite` does not. Are you sure you don't want to have `KinematicBody2D` with `Sprite` as child?

---

**If you want to find out if a position is inside a sprite**, you would do something like this:

```
var inside:bool = p12.get_rect().has_point(p12.to_local(pos))
```

Pay attention that I'm calling `to_local` on the `Sprite`. If you are using local coordinates, it is important what they are local to. *I'm, of course, assuming `pos` was in global coordinates to begin with.*

---

**However, if the goal is to find if a position is inside a `PhysicsBody2D`**(such as `KinematicBody2D`), we do something different.

We can do this:

```
func collides(body:PhysicsBody2D, pos:Vector2) -> bool:
    var results := get_world_2d().direct_space_state.intersect_point(pos)
    for result in results:
        if result.collider == body:
            return true
    
    return false
```

As you can imagine that would be a waste of effort if we are going over an array like you do. Since `intersect_point` is already telling us the `PhysicsBody2D`, you would approach this differently. Something like this:

```
func wich_piece(pos:Vector2):
    var bodies := []
    var results := get_world_2d().direct_space_state.intersect_point(pos)
    for result in results:
        bodies.append(result.collider)

    for piece in pieces:
        var body := ((piece as Sprite).get_node("KinematicBody2D") as KinematicBody)
        if bodies.has(body):
            return piece

    return null
```

---

**But if all you actually want is to find out when the user clicks a `KinematicBody2D`. Set `input_pickable` to `true`. The you will get `"mouse_entered"`, `"mouse_exited`" and `"input_event"` signals. Plus calls to `_input_event`.**

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want to detect a mouse click inside a sprite?

I'm assuming your sprite is inside a `KinematicBody2D` Like this:

[image]

Connect The signal `input_event()` in `KinematicBody2D` to any script and check if the mouse is clicked inside it:

[image]

```
func _on_KinematicBody2D_input_event(viewport, event, shape_idx):
    if(event.is_pressed()):
        print("pressed!")
```

Now every time I click I get a signal like this:

[image]